# всегда ли выделяют прямую речь?

Tags: прямая-речь

Можно ли не брать прямую речь в кавычки и почему? Возможен ли вариант: «Поздравляем всех участников торгов и говорим спасибо за выбор»? Или надо писать: “Поздравляем всех участников торгов и говорим: «Спасибо за выбор»”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае кавычки не требуются:

*Поздравляем всех участников торгов и **говорим спасибо** (= благодарим) за выбор.*

Вопрос № 276983
Добрый день! В предложении "Мы говорим спасибо за тепло..." нужно ли брать слово "спасибо" в кавычки?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
**Кавычки не требуются.**

Но при желании выделить и подчеркнуть слова благодарности можно использовать обычное оформление прямой речи (при этом после двоеточия в устной речи делается пауза):

*Поздравляем всех участников торгов и говорим: "Спасибо за выбор".*

Из словаря:

**СПАСИБО.** I. частица. Выражает благодарность. С. за помощь. С. вам от всех нас за радушие, за угощение.

Пример: И я говорю: «Спасибо за эту радость…»  [Алексей Иванов.  (1990-1991)]

Comment: О паузе важно: я прочувствовала разницу. Спасибо.

Comment: Двоеточие - это не пауза, а показатель смены интонации. Пауза за тире закреплена.

Comment: Кто же это паузу  за тире закрепил (хотелось бы узнать автора)? Даже Розенталь говорит о предупредительной паузе, характерной для двоеточия (хотя обычно в правилах приводится  по преимуществу грамматическое решение).

Comment: Двоеточие говорит о том, что слово перед ним вводное. У двоеточия нету показателя паузы, но так как вводное слово само по себе может вызывать паузу, поэтому и кажется, что двоеточие говорит о ней.

Comment: У меня возникают следующие вопросы: При чем тут вводное слово? Что значит показатель паузы, первый раз такой термин слышу? А всё остальное для понимания просто недоступно.  К сожалению, продолжать диалог не имеет  смысла. Иногда мне кажется, что  у Вас так много мыслей, что Вы успеваете записывать только некоторые из них, поэтому понять Вас трудно. К тому же полноценное общение здесь возможно только в рамках правил, когда собеседники пользуются одинаковой терминологией.